# Advanced Edit of TDocument locks up the UI

Tags: multithreading, caliburn.micro

My Caliburn Micro UI gets locked up because of a rather advanced set of controls contained in a TDocument.   I have tried several different Async approaches to move the activity to another thread, but without success.  Here is a simplified view of the code.  You may recognize it because it is taken from the ***Hello Screens*** sample application.

To see briefly how the Document Conductor Works, here is the interface:

```
Public MustInherit Class DocumentWorkspace(Of TDocument As {Class, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDeactivate, IHaveDisplayName})
    Inherits Conductor(Of TDocument).Collection.OneActive
    Implements IDocumentWorkspace

    Protected Sub New()

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Icon As String Implements IWorkspace.Icon
    Public MustOverride Property IconName As String Implements IWorkspace.IconName
    Public Property PixelLabTransitions As BindableCollection(Of Transition)
    Public Property ScreenTransition As Transition
    Public Property State As DocumentWorkspaceState
    Public Property Status As String Implements IWorkspace.Status
    Protected ReadOnly Property Conductor As IConductor

    Public Overrides Sub ActivateItem(item As TDocument)
    Public Sub Edit(child As TDocument)
    Public Sub Hide()
    Public Sub Show() Implements IWorkspace.Show
End Class
```

Here is the offending code:

```
                _SelectedDesignerElement = value
                'adjust Count located next to Icon 
                vm.DisplayName = value.DesignerDisplayText
                count += 1
                vm.IsDirty = True
                'the next line of code works but 
                'disables the UI for a long time
                Edit(vm)
```

So the simplest way I can show the problem is to try to move this long activity to another thread:

```
                'Plan to show a Busy indicator here

                'Below I have tried to move the edit to another thread
                'but this simply does not work

                Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                          Edit(vm)
                                                      End Sub)
                t.Wait()


                'Plan to remove Busy indicator here
```

Does anyone have a better idea how to free up the UI for this long winded process?

BTW The problem is clearly the fact that the Edit(VM) is not happy on another thread, because I tested the same approach with a Busy indicator using just a counter to create a delay and the Start Busy / End Busy work just fine and the UI remains responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The epiphany happened after I awoke in the middle of the night.
The Hello Screens Project was imported into a current version of Visual Studio (2015) but it never dawned on me that the targeted Framework would remain the same as the original project.  So the Framework was pointing to a version prior to Async and Await support.

I have completed adding a Public Domain Busy Indicator to the Caliburn.Micro Hello Screens sample project.  There are several different situations where you may incur the need for a Busy indicator and there are several different ways to activate the control. For example I found that the place to Activate Busy in my original question is: in the DocumentWorkspace as shown here.

```
    Public Async Sub ShowAsync() Implements HelloScreensWPF.Framework.IWorkspace.ShowAsync
        'Notice that this Sub is Async and the Name is changed from Show (In the CM Sample) to Show Async
        'Not sure this is the very best way but it works pretty good
        'Anytime the user clicks an icon at the bottom of the UI this sub is called
        Dim haveActive = TryCast(Parent, IHaveActiveItem)
        If haveActive IsNot Nothing AndAlso haveActive.ActiveItem Is Me Then
            DisplayName = IconName
            State = DocumentWorkspaceState.Master
        Else
            'We need to have access to the ShellViewModel
            Dim Svm = CType(Parent, ShellViewModel)
            'Activate the Busy indicator

            'The BusyIndicatorViewModel has a built in '200 µ Sec Delay
            'So if it is Deactivated before it 'fires' the user will not see a
            'flash of an unnecessary Busy Indicator
            Svm.ShellBusyIndicator.ShowBusyIndicator(True, True, "Loading", IconName)

            'You will need to push the conductor ActivateItem off to another thread for a real application and
            'get rid of the Sample Task.Delay here
            Await Task.Delay(4000)

            Conductor.ActivateItem(Me)
            Dim list = CType(Parent, IConductor).GetChildren

            'Deactivate Busy Indicator
            Svm.ShellBusyIndicator.ShowBusyIndicator(False)

        End If
    End Sub
```

If anyone would like a copy of the HelloScreens with Busy Solution, just send me an email ranck at aqsi.net with an @.